# Why is my mode program not printing anything?

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry for click bait title, but it is my problem, and I can't really change to wording without losing the question.

I have the following code which is meant to select a file, read it, and find it's mode, and I think I got it done, but I have one issue

```
public class ModeFinder 
{

    public static int countDoubles(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);


        int count = 0;

        while (reader.hasNextDouble())
        {
            count++;
            reader.nextDouble();
        }

        reader.close();
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        String filename;

        FileDialog filePicker = new FileDialog(new JFrame());
        filePicker.setVisible(true);

        filename = filePicker.getFile();
        String folderName = filePicker.getDirectory();
        filename = folderName + filename;
        System.out.println("filename = " +filename);

        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (inputFile);

        int maxValue = 0,
                maxCount = 0;
        int[] a = new int[countDoubles(inputFile)];

        while (fileReader.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
            {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) 
                {
                    if (a[j] == a[i]) 
                        count++;
                }
                if (count > maxCount) 
                {
                    maxCount = count;
                    maxValue = a[i];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The most common grade is: " +maxValue);
    }
}
```

The last bit with the most common grade doesn't even print and I don't know why.

Comment: Where are you populating a[] contents?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, instead of dumping the entire file

Comment: You need to actually read the numbers in the file. Your main loop currently isn't doing that. Also, your main loop is about `int`s and your count function is about `double`s. That mismatch isn't going to help anything.

Comment: mikea has your answer (+1 to it), but to help you for future similar problems, you will want to learn some debugging techniques. Something as simple as using println statements within your program will often show you where your problem is, and then how to solve it.

Comment: Well I need you guys to see what my program is trying to do because it's a problem without a compiling error, and it's frustrating, but thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling nextInt to get the value from the file so your while loop is going to loop forever. You need something like:

```
    while (fileReader.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        int value = fileReader.nextInt();
        ...
```